# Netbeans Glassfish don't start anymore

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

When I try to start the Glassfish server an Information window appears saying:
" Could not connect to admin listener for GlassFish Server 3.1.2
Verify that Netbeans can make outbound connections to localhost :4848 ".

And if I close that window I can see that there are opened lots of windows with:
Networtk communication problem
" Could not establish a reliable connection with localhost (localhost:4848)
Error message:
Permission Denied: connect ".

See these images:

http://postimage.org/image/9po31npo7/

http://postimage.org/image/pdq5c32m3/

**FIXED** :

The problem was Java. Not Netbeans nor glassfish. The Java engine needed to be reinstalled.

Comment: it looks to me like a local firewall is blocking the connections. Java, and by extension Netbeans, is not going to lie to you. It says permission denied so the connection really is denied. So what is denying the connection?

Comment: It worked before, I just wanted to see the project again and all these errors appeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receive an error pointing to this line from build-impl.xml:

```
    <nbdeploy clientModuleUri="${client.module.uri}" clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Any idea?

**FIXED** :

The problem was Java. Not Netbeans nor glassfish. The Java engine needed to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

Go to services tab and expand servers and right click on glassfish server and choose properties in that select java tab and deselect use IDE proxy settings and then try.

Comment: Try removing the glassfish and adding it again some configuration might be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

May be the port is used by another process. I tried to stop other services like SQL server ms SQL oracle and then the error has been solved, it's working properly.